# How do I return 10 rows where 5 is for a specific value?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for special offers (shopping). The table contains special offers from 50 stores, 5 from Oslo and 45 from other cities in Norway.

By default, I want to select 10 rows by date, country and city.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT b.name, a.title, a.shortDescription, a.longDescription, a.startTime, a.endTime, b.fk_countryID, b.city
FROM sl_sale a
LEFT JOIN sl_store b ON a.fk_storeID = b.id
WHERE a.endTime >= NOW()
AND b.fk_countryID = 'NO'
AND b.city = 'Oslo'
ORDER BY a.startTime ASC
LIMIT 10
```

My problem is that it will only return 5 rows because `b.city = 'Oslo'`.

How can I return 10 rows, where the other 5 are from other cities where `a.endTime >= NOW()`?
Do I have to make two queries?

Comment: I would select a union, where the first take 5 records with `AND b.city = 'Oslo'` and select the second union with `AND b.city != 'Oslo'`

Comment: As noted by @JellyBelly, if you explicitly want 5 from Oslo, and 5 from everywhere else, you would need to do it as a Union... The other examples will just get 10 regardless of Oslo.

Comment: @DRap - 5 was just a number. It can be 1, 0 or 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want records for `Olso` first, you could move it from the `WHERE` clause to the `ORDER` clause:

```
SELECT b.name, a.title, a.shortDescription, a.longDescription, a.startTime, a.endTime, b.fk_countryID, b.city
FROM sl_sale a
LEFT JOIN sl_store b ON a.fk_storeID = b.id
WHERE a.endTime >= NOW()
AND b.fk_countryID = 'NO'
ORDER BY b.city = 'Oslo' DESC, a.startTime ASC
LIMIT 10
```

This effectively limits it to 10 results matching that `WHERE` condition, but any rows where `b.city = 'Oslo'` will be ordered to the *top*. **Note:** That could be more than 5 rows.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Didnæt know I could order by value. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Yeah, it's a useful feature and works perfectly for this type of ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.name, a.title, a.shortDescription, a.longDescription, a.startTime, a.endTime,     b.fk_countryID, b.city
FROM sl_sale a
LEFT JOIN sl_store b ON a.fk_storeID = b.id
WHERE b.fk_countryID = 'NO'
AND (a.endTime >= NOW() OR b.city = 'Oslo')
ORDER BY a.startTime ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee he gets the *5 records* for `Olso`.

Comment: Good point.  The other answer's LEFT JOIN is necessary.  Doh.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.name, a.title, a.shortDescription, a.longDescription, a.startTime, a.endTime, b.fk_countryID, b.city
FROM sl_sale a
LEFT JOIN sl_store b ON a.fk_storeID = b.id
WHERE (a.endTime >= NOW() OR b.city='Oslo')
AND b.fk_countryID = 'NO'
ORDER BY a.startTime ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee he gets the *5 records* for `Olso`.